# Make <td> with colspan=2 have 2-column background, another color in each column

Tags: html, background, html-table

is it possible to make `<td colspan="2">` element have 2-column background? I mean that `<td>` has 100% width and the background would be red for 50% of width and blue for the rest 50%:

[image: background preview]

The reason I need this is because of my html markup:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>One column text</td><td>One column text</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>One column text</td><td>One column text</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">This text must flow through the whole table width (through 2 columns width)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>One column text</td><td>One column text</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I think that I can use image as a background but I would prefer some clean HTML/CSS solution...

In addition I can't use gradient background because IE cant show straight line between two colors, it can make only gradient from one color to another and this gradient needs 4 colors

Comment: Can't you just make this two <td>s and have the text in the first one overflow into the second one?

Comment: I didn't managed to overflow it. Can you provide some example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you work with this as a base?
http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ggRHs/4/
I didn't style the table, so you can see what happens better. But it doesn't use colspan, so you can just color each individual table cell as you see fit.

Comment: That looks nice but there's problem with more-than-one-line text

Comment: Oh, I was thinking there's a bigger problem with the line of text being wider than the entire table. It's not perfect. But based on this, can't you come up with something that does satisfy your needs?

Comment: Your example is perfect except that thing that the text overflows out of the table. The table is designed for dynamic data so I can't afford to have a risk that the text will run away out of website. I think that the only acceptable solution today is using background image. However, thanks anyway